# Style (global) variant of hashed class in CSS module

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sass, css-modules

I'm using Next.js (React.js) with CSS (SCSS) modules. I want to style a global class of a hashed class.

```
<div className={`$styles["text"] background--red`}>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70340648/how-to-style-not-hashed-class-in-css-modules-file) and tried it as suggested in the answer. Unfortunately this did not work.

```
.custom-class {
    background: black;
    & :global(.background--red) {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

The rendered CSS should output this:

```
.styles_custom-class__[HASH].background--red {
    background: red;
}
```

Is there a way to style a global variant of a hashed CSS class?